# Volume buttons sometimes crashes the keyboard

Tags: media-buttons

I have a Lenovo s730 with Ubuntu 18,04 installed.

When I use the sound keys they work 50% of the time. Sometimes they just stay pressed and i won't be able to use the keyboard for some time.

Any ideas for a fix?

Comment: Hardware issues have nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: they work on windows

Comment: Clearly it's a software issue, not a hardware issue.